# separate id and onClick for recyclerview items

Tags: onclicklistener, imagebutton, android-recyclerview, android-imagebutton

I created a Recyclerview and it has 20 images(character images). I want separate onClick for each image cause it has different data. I don't know how to set OnClick for each one of them just like imageButtons . I'll appreciate your help